# Command line is too long ... Error when migrating from spark 1.6.1 to 2.3.0

Tags: apache-spark

In Intellij i have this gradle config :

```
ext.sparkVersion = '1.6.1'
ext.scalaVersion = '2.11'
```

And my script is working fine...
But as soon a change to :

```
ext.sparkVersion = '2.3.0'
ext.scalaVersion = '2.11'
```

I'm getting :

> Error running 'SpaceWalk2': Command line is too long. Shorten command line for 
>       SpaceWalk2 or also for Application default configuration

Any idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039414/intellij-command-line-is-too-long-shorten-command-line-for-in-sbt-project

Comment: Sorry I will probably say something stupid, but it's not a sbt project. It's a gradle project, because a don't have build.sbt