# Command line is too long. Shorten command line for Test or also for JUnit default configuration?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

im trying to run my junits, but intellij give me a error:
[image]

I have seen the error on many sites, but the configuration page is different than the current one from intellij.

Now, intellij-idea have this configuration page:
[image]

What would I have to modify to be able to fix it?

Here is my intellij info:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-203.7148.57, built on January 26, 2021 Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. Windows 10 10.0 GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep Memory: 1955M Cores: 8 Non-Bundled Plugins: com.dubreuia, org.sonarlint.idea, org.jetbrains.kotlin

Greetings and thank you very much: D

Comment: Did you already check this ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039414/intellij-command-line-is-too-long-shorten-command-line-for-in-sbt-project

Comment: @AntiqTech Yes, I said that intellij has modified the configuration page and that now that configuration does not appear.

Comment: I see, I thought it was worth a shot giving the link. Anyway, could you please give your IntelliJ's version / build information in your question. It might help us track down a viable solution.

Comment: Sure, here is my intellij information. I'm checking to see if there are updates, or can I downgrade version

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-203.7148.57, built on January 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1955M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.dubreuia, org.sonarlint.idea, org.jetbrains.kotlin

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can find out about this. In the meanwhile please add the that information to the end of your Question. Not all the people would the comments.

Comment: @AntiqTech I solved it. Intellij idea move the option to another site.
Thanks to much for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can shorten the command line, by checking "Shorten Command Line" in the "Add Run Options" menu that is found under "Modify Options" in the "Build and Run" tab for the test configure - as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 11):

From this link: https://devis.cool/quick-fix/quickfix-intellij-idea-command-line-is-too-long-shorten-command-line-for/

Open file from project root folder .idea/workspace.xml, go to section  and add the following:

```
<property name="dynamic.classpath" value="true" />
```

It should look something like this:

```
<component name="PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="dynamic.classpath" value="true" />
    <property name="WebServerToolWindowFactoryState" value="false" />
    <property name="aspect.path.notification.shown" value="true" />
    <property name="last_opened_file_path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/pom.xml" />
    <property name="nodejs_interpreter_path.stuck_in_default_project" value="undefined stuck path" />
    <property name="nodejs_npm_path_reset_for_default_project" value="true" />
</component>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. "Modify Options" menu mentioned in the first answer was not coming for me so tried out this xml file change and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the command line, by checking "Shorten Command Line" in the "Add Run Options" menu that is found under "Modify Options" in the "Build and Run" tab for the test configure - as shown below.

This option worked for me. Make sure you are checking the below shorten command line argument properly